# How to copy parent site including workflows without having to republish them?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, reusable-workflow

We're having issues in getting reusable workflows linked to different lists to directly work when creating a copy of a parent site.

We're trying to build a SharePoint parent site that works as a template for Program Management. So, with every new Program, we create a copy with content of our template, ready to be used.

Everything works fine, except for the workflows. **Our template site includes a number of reusable workflows linked to the lists. When we create a copy, they're copied but don't initially work.** Every time we have a new copy **we have to** go to SharePoint designer, **republish them** and link them again. We have the same issue with list workflows.

As people will request this template, and automatically get a copy of the site, it's important that** those workflows are enabled and working without having to republish them.

We have previously done this on a subsite (so copying a subsite under the same parent site) and the workflows were directly working.